# Nested JSON objects from Spring RestClient and Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson-databind

I have a rest client that will be getting JSON back from an endpoint. I would like to just get what is in the data[].

```
{
    "responseStatus": "SUCCESS",
    "responseDetails": {
        "limit": 1000,
        "offset": 0,
        "size": 2,
        "total": 2
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "00P000000001M01",
            "name__v": "Foo",
            "status__v": [
                "active__v"
            ],
            "abbreviation__c": "F170053",
            "internal_name__c": "Foo",
            "therapeutic_area__c": [
                "neurology__c"
            ],
            "external_id__v": "84",
            "generic_name__c": "Foo",
            "scientific_name__c": null
        },
        {
            "id": "00P000000001N01",
            "name__v": "Bar",
            "status__v": [
                "active__v"
            ],
            "abbreviation__c": "B333334",
            "internal_name__c": "Bar",
            "therapeutic_area__c": [
                "bone_muscle_joint__c"
            ],
            "external_id__v": "101",
            "generic_name__c": "Bar",
            "scientific_name__c": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Because I will make other calls which will return different fields in the data[], I wanted to map each type to a POJO so I used @JSONProperty

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Product extends VBase{
    private String fNumber;
    private String genericName;
    private String scientificName;
    private String therapeuticArea;


    public String getFNumber() {
        return fNumber;
    }

    @JsonProperty("abbreviation__c")
    private void unpackFNumber(Map<String,Object> abbreviation__c){
        fNumber = ((Map<String,Object>)abbreviation__c.get("data")).get("abbreviation__c").toString();
    }
    public void setLyNumber(String fNumber) {
        this.fNumber = fNumber;
    }

    public String getGenericName() {
        return genericName;
    }


    @JsonProperty("generic_name__c")
    private void unpackGenericName(Map<String,Object> generic_name__c){
        genericName = ((Map<String,Object>)generic_name__c.get("data")).get("generic_name__c").toString();
    }
    public String getScientificName() {
        return scientificName;
    }

    @JsonProperty("scientific_name__c")
    private void unpackScientificName(Map<String,Object>sName){
        scientificName = ((Map<String,Object>)sName.get("data")).get("scientific_name__c").toString();
    }

    public String getTherapeuticArea() {
        return therapeuticArea;
    }

    @JsonProperty("therapeutic_area__c")
    private void unpackTheraputicArea(Map<String,Object>tArea){
        therapeuticArea=((Map<String,Object>)tArea.get("data")).get("therapeutic_area__c").toString();
    }
}
```

I have tried various ways of just getting the data[].

```
 HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpReq);
        ResponseEntity<Product[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request,Product[].class);

//ResponseEntity<Product[]> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url,request,Product[].class ,parmMap);
```

What I have been trying to avoid is making a ResponseDetail POJO with a Data[] as a field.  I know it will work but because the fields in the data[] will change based on the endpoint.

Can I use a wrapper class with a List to represent the data[] as all of the POJO will extend VBase?

Here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class [Lcom.lilly.models.Product;] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.lilly.models.Product[]` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.lilly.models.Product[]` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring a POJO class as below code, and then you can get data property from the POJO.

```
@Data
public class Example {
    private String responseStatus;
    private ResponseDetails responseDetails;
    private List<Data> data;

    @lombok.Data
    public static class ResponseDetails {
        private int limit;
        private int offset;
        private int size;
        private int total;
    }

    @lombok.Data
    public static class Data {
        private String id;
        private String name__v;
        private String abbreviation__c;
        private String internal_name__c;
        private String external_id__v;
        private String generic_name__c;
        private Object scientific_name__c;
        private List<String> status__v;
        private List<String> therapeutic_area__c;
    }

    @lombok.Data
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class Product {
        @JsonProperty("name__v")
        private String fNumber;
        @JsonProperty("generic_name__c")
        private String genericName;
        @JsonProperty("scientific_name__c")
        private String scientificName;
        @JsonProperty("therapeutic_area__c")
        private List<String> therapeuticArea;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonResult = "{\"responseStatus\":\"SUCCESS\",\"responseDetails\":{\"limit\":1000,\"offset\":0,\"size\":2,\"total\":2},\"data\":[{\"id\":\"00P000000001M01\",\"name__v\":\"Foo\",\"status__v\":[\"active__v\"],\"abbreviation__c\":\"F170053\",\"internal_name__c\":\"Foo\",\"therapeutic_area__c\":[\"neurology__c\"],\"external_id__v\":\"84\",\"generic_name__c\":\"Foo\",\"scientific_name__c\":null},{\"id\":\"00P000000001N01\",\"name__v\":\"Bar\",\"status__v\":[\"active__v\"],\"abbreviation__c\":\"B333334\",\"internal_name__c\":\"Bar\",\"therapeutic_area__c\":[\"bone_muscle_joint__c\"],\"external_id__v\":\"101\",\"generic_name__c\":\"Bar\",\"scientific_name__c\":null}]}";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            Example example = objectMapper.readValue(jsonResult, new TypeReference<Example>() {
            });
            //you can get data[] via example.getData()
            System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(example.getData()));

            List<Product> products = objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(example.getData()), new TypeReference<List<Product>>() {
            });
            //you can also parse data[] as List<Product>
            System.out.println(JSONObject.toJSONString(products));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the best way to do it if I have 30 other POJO that represent what could be in the data []?  I recognize that I might need a ResponseDetail as that part does not change for any call I make.  What is in the data[] changes.

Comment: Does not work due to MismatchedInputException.  I saw this before when tried your answer and added an error [] to figure out an issue.  I had to move the error class from an inner class to its own class.  Can't do that with Data (reasons given above).

Comment: Obviously you can see the error info in the stack, which is `MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of com.lilly.models.Product[] out of START_OBJECT token.` It means your json string could not match your pojo property. Maybe you can change `Product[]` to `List<Product>` and change `String` to `List<String> therapeuticArea`. BTW, it works in my answer code.

Comment: I have changed the POJO to exactly what you posted with the lombok data annotations.  It will load the Data class but not the Product class.  Part of the issue is probably that my string is coming from the REST call and that I am using SpringBoot and thus the built in Jackson data bind.  I can make this work in a round-about fashion.